# Prevent resolvconf package assign localhost if named bind9/dnsmasq is found on host

Tags: linux, bind9, resolvconf

Resolvconf is a package born to handle different specific situations like lans with dhcp, vpn, and other situation where everyone try to change manually the /etc/resolv.conf file.

It has an algorithm where the max priority is obtained with a list of interfaces, as example tun and dhcp clients goes over a ppp connection.

**/etc/resolvconf/interface-order**

```
# interface-order(5)
lo.inet6
lo.inet
lo.@(dnsmasq|pdnsd)
lo.!(pdns|pdns-recursor)
lo
tun*
tap*
hso*
em+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
p+([0-9])p+([0-9])?(_+([0-9]))*
eth*([^.]).inet6
eth*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
eth*([^.]).inet
eth*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
eth*
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet6
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).ip6.@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).inet
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*([^.]).@(dhclient|dhcpcd|pump|udhcpc)
@(ath|wifi|wlan)*
ppp*
*
```

My problem is that if you have resolvconf package and you also install a DNS Server like NAMED BIND9 or DNSMASQ, the resolvconf software will assign automatically top precedence to 127.0.0.1..

Well I don't want that, I want resolvconf package works normally as if bind9/dnsmasq wasn't installed. But I can't find an option like "ignore local dns as possible dns choice" into resolvconf software configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine seems after some tries i found a solution...

By commenting all the localhost lines in interface-order file, expecially this two lines:

```
# lo.@(dnsmasq|pdnsd)
# lo.!(pdns|pdns-recursor)
```

Everything worked as wanted ;)